# What is TX status timeout and do I have to worry about it?

Tags: kernel, logs, wifi, fedora

Recently, after performing a routine software upgrade, I notice a huge surge in the number of warnings from the kernel that goes like this:

> warning   kern [10839.717480] phy0 -> rt2800usb_txdone: Warning - Got TX
>   status for an empty queue 0, dropping
>  warning kern [10839.895305]
>   phy0 -> rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout
>   for entry 11 in queue 2
>  warning   kern [10839.895325] phy0 ->
>   rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout for
>   entry 11 in queue 2
>  warning   kern [10839.895327] phy0 ->
>   rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout for
>   entry 11 in queue 2

I think it has something to do with either the newly installed `kernel-3.9.4-200` or `wpa_supplicant-1.1-1` as the warnings appeared soon after these were installed. From the message itself, I think it has something to do with the wireless transmission, but not sure whether this is something serious as it is filling up my log quite rapidly.

I am using a TP-Link wireless USB adapter. Has anyone encountered such problem or know whether it is something that I need to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be an active bug in the rt2800usb driver. There's an open issue in the Fedora's bugzilla database here, titled:

- [Bug 913631 - Slow wireless connection using rt2800usb driver (Asus USB-N13 dongle)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=913631).

#### TX status timeout

The term TX refers to transfer (i.e. sending) and RX refers to receiver (i.e. receiving). I would say that it is something that you need to worry about given these messages mean your wireless driver & hardware combination aren't working 100% correctly. So you'll likely see either slow network access and/or flaky network connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems that the bug report was filed due to slow connection. Comment 8 indicates that the user only got those errors I described above after he upgraded his kernel to 3.9. As my network connection has always been slow/flaky due to the distance between my adapter and the router, does that constitute an actual problem?

Comment: I would live with it if you're sure it's a distance issue. You might want to spend some time seeing if it's a wireless-N vs. Wireless A/B issue. We've mitigated an issue we were having at work by disabling the wireless-N support on the AP and also on the laptops as part of the driver setup. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks again. For now, the error seems to have gone away after another round of software updates. Could be due to some bug with some software. But can certainly rule out the kernel and wpa supplicant since these were not updated this time.